# How do I map my Id attribute to the Ulid type using a yml file?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to mapping my Id attribute as Symfony\Component\Ulid using yml file.

This is my yml file:

```
App\Entity\User:
  type: entity
  repositoryClass: App\Entity\UserRepository
  table: user
  id:
    id:
      type: ulid
      unique: true
      generator:
        strategy: CUSTOM
        class: Symfony\Component\Uid\Ulid
```

When I run the command to generate the "migrations" I am getting the following error: "Cannot instantiate custom generator, no class has been defined"

How do I map my Id attribute to the Ulid type using a yml file?

The mapping below using PHP 8 attributes works:

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Uid\Ulid;

class User
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'ulid', unique: true)]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy: 'CUSTOM')]
    #[ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class: 'doctrine.ulid_generator')]
    private $id;

    public function getId(): ?Ulid
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

}
```

But I need to use the mapping with yml.

Comment: I got the same thing. Nobody answers :((

Answer (score 0):

I solved it as follows:

```
App\Entity\User: 
  type: entity 
  repositoryClass: App\Repository\UserRepository 
  table: "`user`"
  id:
    id:
      type: ulid
      unique: true
      generator:
        strategy: CUSTOM
      customIdGenerator:
        class: doctrine.ulid_generator
```